# In tableview, scrolling erases the previous items chosen with combobox

Tags: java, javafx

Whenever I add item through combobox in tableview, after scrolling, the previous items of combobox gets erased? How solve this issue. Am using JavaFx. My items get disappear whenever it scrolls.

**Here My code**

```
private void Showtabledata() {

    meta=FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    meta1=FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try {
        Connection conn = DB.getConnection();
        ResultSet rs2 = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM testgroup_master");
        while (rs2.next()) {
            String test=rs2.getString("groupname");
            meta1.add(test);
            meta.add(new Patienttabledetails(rs2.getString("groupname")));

        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println("Error" + ex);
    }
    testCat_tbl.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(new DefaultStringConverter(),meta1));
    testCat_tbl.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Patienttabledetails, String>>()

        {
            @Override
            public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Patienttabledetails, String> event) {
                System.out.println("Value"+event.getNewValue());
            }
        });
    table1.setEditable(true);
    table1.setItems(null);
    table1.setItems(meta);

}
```

How I can avoid to disappear values in combo box?

[image: Image 1][image: image 2]
[image: image 3]

Above screen shots showing the errors. Whenever am scrolling the above selected items values are get disappear.

Comment: most probably something wrong in the code you are not showing - please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify a `onEditCommit` handler, the `ComboBoxTableCell` will does not attempt to set the new value to the property returned form the `cellValueFactory` when a new value is selected in the `ComboBox`.

This means you need to do this yourself, if you specify a `onEditCommit` handler for the new value to be stored in your item class:

```
testCat_tbl.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Patienttabledetails, String>>()

    {
        @Override
        public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Patienttabledetails, String> event) {
            System.out.println("Value"+event.getNewValue());

            // TODO: replace setter name by suitable setter of your Patienttabledetails class here
            event.getRowValue().setSomeProperty(event.getNewValue());
        }
    });
```